# calling shell commands from code by design?

Tags: ruby, linux, unix, console-application

The Unix philosophy teaches that we should develop small programs that do one thing well.  It also teaches that we should separate policy from mechanics.  I guess one way to take this is to design a text-based shell command first and build a gui on top of that later (if desired).

I truly like the idea that small programs can be composed (piped together) into more complex systems.  I also like the fact that simple, focused designs should theoretically need less maintenance than a monolithic system that binds all its rules together.

How sound would it be to program something (in Ruby or Python for example) that relegates some of its functionality to shell commands called straight from the code?  Taking this a step further, does it make sense to deliberately design a shell command that is intended to be called directly from code (compiled or scripted)?  Obviously, this would only make sense if the shell command had some worthy console use.

I can't say from my experience that this is a practice I've seen much of.  More times than not task-specific code relies on task-specific libraries.  Of course, it's  possible that, unbeknownst to me, I have made use of libraries which are actually just wrappers around shell commands.  (Or rather the shell command is a wrapper around some library.)

Comment: I asked this back before the advent of microservices.  Had I asked today I might have gotten different answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The unix paradigm is modularity. You should write your program as a bunch of modules, which can then be extracted into multiple programs if you want to. However, executing a new program whenever you'd like to make a function call is slow and unpractical.

Comment: +1, the core of UNIX philosophy is modularity and composability as concepts. If some Ruby module/class may be run independently, you can always expose its functionality both for the command-line and as a Ruby library.